# "Uncaught TypeError: fileReader.readAsDataurl is not a function" Automatic Function Casing Problem

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to convert a PDF file to base64.

I've seen a few different examples, the one below is the one I'm sticking with for this question.
But I think I've narrowed down the problem to reader.readAsDataURL(file);
After trying the examples I've run into the same problem on all of them.

*Uncaught TypeError: fileReader.readAsDataurl is not a function*

I did some research and came to the conclusion that the fault was in the casing, I tested the file in the w3 schools input with lower case and it gave the same problem I came to on the webserver.

Then I switched the case to capital and it suddenly worked. However, when I switched the case in my webserver the problem persisted.
So I checked the console and realized the casing was automatically changed from fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad); to fileReader.readAsDataurl(fileToLoad);. Since the W3 schools input had an identical problem when it was lowercase, I was wondering if there was a way to force the function name to have capitals.

I've checked these two and a few others and they don't seem to run into this problem.

[ReadAsDataURL() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740523/readasdataurl-doesnt-work)

[JavaScript readAsDataurl is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272619/javascript-readasdataurl-is-not-a-function/30272620)

The second seems like how I could deal with this but the page will automatically switch all "readAsDataURL" to lowercase.
Anyone else have this problem? Is there a workaround or is it a problem with my webserver? Should be I asking the company's support line instead?

TL;DR Is there a way to prevent a page from automatically changing the case of a function name? (Or is the problem somewhere else entirely?)

```js
    function convertToBase64() {
        //Read File
        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("inputFile").files;
        //Check File is not Empty
        if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
            // Select the very first file from list
            var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
            // FileReader function for read the file.
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            var base64;
            // Onload of file read the file content
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                // Print data in console
                console.log(base64);
            };
            // Convert data to base64
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }
    }
```

```html
<input id="inputFile" type="file" onchange="convertToBase64();" />
```

Comment: When I run the snippet in your question, it works fine.

Comment: If something on your server is altering your content *in any way*, that's a problem.

Comment: @Pointy Yea I was afraid of that, if there's no way to keep the case from switching then I'll go ahead and send support a ticket. Thanks though, I appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested the response from the support ticket and it works. The webserver runs pages through a system that finds and substitutes many words or phrases for others. What I ended up needing to do was change:

```
fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
```

to

```
fileReader['readAsDataURL'](fileToLoad);
```

Hopefully this is useful for the two other people that would ever have a problem like this.